# Modifying variables from another file

Tags: node.js, require, var

i've got this in a file called voting_Request.js:

```
else
        {
            count1 = 0;
            count2 = 0;
            boolCheck = true;
            module.exports.count1 = count1;
            module.exports.count2 = count2;
        }
```

and i've got this as well in a file called vote.js:

```
var request = require('./voting_Request.js');
async run(message,args){
    var c1 = request.count1;
    var c2 = request.count2;
    if(!request.boolCheck){
        message.reply('No ongoing votings please try again when a voting is available');
    }
    else{
        if(request.voted.indexOf(message.author.tag) > -1){
            message.reply("You have already voted!");
        }
        else{
            request.noVote = false;
            switch (args) {
                case '1':
                    c1++;
                    message.reply('Thanks for voting!');
                    request.voted.push(message.author.tag);
                    break;
                case '2':
                    c2++;
                    message.reply('Thanks for voting!');
                    request.voted.push(message.author.tag);
                    break;
                default:
                    message.reply(args + ' is not an available option');
            }
            module.exports.c1 = c1;
            module.exports.c2 = c2;
        }
    }
}
```

and basicallyinstead of taking the VALUE of count1 and count2 from the request file and only copying it into new variables in vote.js, i want to modify them from vote.js but the value in count1 and count2 will change depending on vote.js.

Thanks for the help!